# Can I use facebook-connect as my user authentication?

Tags: iphone, authentication, facebook, webserver

I'm building a iPhone App, that communicates with a webserver (Java webapp) using REST (XML over http). In my prototype I used http's basic-authentication to allow access and identify the user, using username and password. Since there should be friendships and profiles in my app, I want to use facebook-connect so I don't have to implement it and the users don't have to manage there friends and profiles twice. When I use fb-connect, I may even go without all the basic user management stuff, like create a new user, change password and so on.

So here is my question: Is it possible to use facebook-connect as my one and only user authentication? And more importantly: How can I authenticate the user while communicating with the webserver?

To clarify: I don't want to link the facebook account to my user accounts, I want to use it instead.

Comment: Where you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: @Oh Danny Boy: No, sadly I never finished the idea and I still don't know if it would work, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Facebook Graph API to do this. Here are some links to get started

A tutorial on the subject:

http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth2-graph-api

Some objective-C work someone did to make life easier:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

The official graph API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Yes, I know these APIs, but can the authenticated mobile app send the auth-token to the server? And is the web app able to verify that token and use it to access facebook informations?

Comment: Good question. The accessToken should be available, after login, from the Facebook Objective-C object as a property (using the facebook ios library from above). Now if you pass this accessToken back to your server and have your server try to do a facebook Graph API call, then it should work. If your server gets an error, then the access token is no good. Of course I haven't tried it myself. Maybe the access token's are IP specific or something, but I doubt it. Worth a try.

Comment: Also, this page has a nice tutorial for both iOS and Android flows using the Facebook mobile SDKs.: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/

Comment: By the way you'll also need to get the user's facebook ID which you can pass back to your server as well. This is what should be used instead of say a username. The userid can be retrieved via this call: http://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=....